# How can I populate one UITableView with two queries?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a tableview that needs to display all friend requests that a user is involved in (both sent and received.)

However, the only way I can think of to do this is to perform two separate queries: one where the username is equal to the requester, and one where the username is equal to the requested.

Is this the best route to go? If so, how do I set up the code?

My code keeps crashing the app on  `func cellForRowAtIndexPath()`  on `let dateString3 = timePeriodFormatter.stringFromDate(pendingDates[indexPath.row])` saying that the array is out of range.

This is what I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    users = []
    user = PFUser()
    objectId = String()
    pendingDates = []
    username = String()
    usernames = []
    tradeIdentifier = String()
    tradeId = []
    pendingRequestsId = []

    var requestsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
    requestsQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: "transit")
    requestsQuery.whereKey("completed", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    requestsQuery.whereKey("completed", notEqualTo: "complete")
    requestsQuery.whereKey("requestedUsername", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    requestsQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    requestsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    pendingDates.append(object.createdAt! as NSDate)
                    usernames.append(object["requesterUsername"] as! String)
                    users.append(object["requester"] as! PFUser)
                    pendingRequestsId.append(object.objectId!)
                    tradeId.append("requested")
                }
            }
            var requestsQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
            requestsQuery2.whereKey("status", equalTo: "transit")
            requestsQuery2.whereKey("completed", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            requestsQuery2.whereKey("completed", notEqualTo: "complete")
            requestsQuery2.whereKey("requesterUsername", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            requestsQuery2.orderByDescending("createdAt")
            requestsQuery2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                            pendingDates.append(object.createdAt! as NSDate)
                            usernames.append(object["requestedUsername"] as! String)
                            users.append(object["requested"] as! PFUser)
                            pendingRequestsId.append(object.objectId!)
                            tradeId.append("requester")

                        }
                    }
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                } else {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    println(error)
                }
                //self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return usernames.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: PendingTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PendingTableViewCell

    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row] as String

    let timePeriodFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d"

    let dateString3 = timePeriodFormatter.stringFromDate(pendingDates[indexPath.row])

    cell.date.text = dateString3

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    username = usernames[indexPath.row]
    objectId = pendingRequestsId[indexPath.row] as String
    tradeIdentifier = tradeId[indexPath.row]
    user = users[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: self)        
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget exactly what the syntax is because it's been awhile since I've worked with parse, but I had similar funtionality in an app that I built. Parse lets you create two queries seperately and then join them together before the call is made so as to return the result of two individual queries.

Since the queries you're trying to run are in the same class you can do something like this:

```
var requestQuery1 = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
requestQuery1.whereKey("status", equalTo: "Transit")
//add other query paremeter here
var requestQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Requests)
//add query paremeters
```

And then here is where you would run the two queries together:

```
var joinQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([requestQuery1, requestQuery2])
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, but unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue!

Comment: It's crashing on that line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` function? what happens if you comment out that line of code, does the application behave the way you would expect it to? You could also wrap it in an `if...let` block which will at least prevent it from crashing. As far as fixing the issue, you'll probably have to set a break point and see if the `pendingDates` array has the values you expect in it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If I comment it out, everything is normal (except for the obvious that the displayed date is my placeholder).

Comment: Actually, just tried an if/else block, and got it fixed. For some reason, `object.createdAt` is taking longer to retrieve than the rest of the objects in the query. It is very slow, causing the crash as it take too long to populate the array. The if/else prevents the crash, and self.collectionView.reloadData() makes the date appear as soon as it's ready.